# Mailgun events API timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, mailgun

I'm making calls to the Mailgun events API but I'm confused by the timestamp format. Timestamps show as `"timestamp": 1542251497.6072` or the longer format `1542358648.178141`.

I can't find any reference to it in the documentation except their claim to follow "RFC822" specification.

How can I parse/convert these timestamps into JavaScript Date objects (GMT preferably)?

Comment: It sounds like you may be unfamiliar with timestamps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970).

Comment: `new Date(timestamp * 1000)` will do (returns "2018-11-15T03:11:37.607Z").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already are using `moment` simply use the [**`unix`**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) method:

```
moment.unix(1542251497.6072).format()    // "2018-11-14T19:11:37-08:00"
moment.unix(1542358648.178141).format()  // "2018-11-16T00:57:28-08:00"
```

Which:

> Similar to new Date(Number), you can create a moment by passing an
>   integer value representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix
>   Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).